# document.write("some text") erases URL and about:blank is shown

Tags: javascript, html, dom, window.open, document.write

I have written
 `1. var win=window.open("problem.html");

2. win.document.write("some text")`

When I don't write 2nd line a new tab opens with the `problem.html` appended in the current URL.

But when I include 2nd line, it shows a new tab with text `some text` but URL is `about:blank`.
 Please suggest a way so that my URL won't change.

Comment: Do you have any extensions active? The unexpected write might cause an extension to crash. In chrome try in incognito mode (with all extensions disabled).

Comment: Don't use document.write if you don't understand how it works. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write

Comment: @AshleyCoolman, you are right bro. I have an extension called <code>new tab</code>, when I tried in incognito it works fine.

Comment: Nice. Its easy to forget that your extensions have free reign over your DOM, filling your network tab with their garbage requests, and generally doing whatever they want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one worked for me Let me know if it does for you:

```
window.open('NAME, anything here it wont appear your url to show name will appear in  window, '_blank').document.location = "URL TO SHOW"; 

window.open('NAME To Show', '_blank').document.write("TEXT TO SHOW");
```

See Document.write(); documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write

Answer (score -2):

Don't use the name of document in first argument of `window.open`, use `url` like `http://myaddress.com/problem.html`.

According the documentation at [W3C School](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp):

> URL: Specifies the URL of the page to open. If no URL is specified, a new window with about:blank is opened

Comment: `problem.html` is a URL. It's a relative URL.